# return 60 column table from one stored procedure into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[outer_sp]
        @PrmIdUsAD  nchar(128)
        ,@PrmAnnee  smallint
        ,@PrmMois   tinyint
        ,@PrmIdAct  tinyint
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @DateMin datetime, @DateMax datetime, @idAgence nchar(2), @nomAgence nchar(50);

EXEC inner_sp( @DateMin, @DateMax, @idAgence, @nomAgence)
...
END
```

inner_sp ends up by (table has 60 columns)

```
SELECT
ISNULL(nomAgence, '') AS nomAgence,
ISNULL(chemin, '') AS chemin,
...
FROM #temp_arbo_of_4
ORDER BY chemin
END
```

How do I retrieve this output table in the calling stored procedure ?
I know some variables are not set, but this is outside the scope of question.

Comment: [Let me count the ways](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html). The "correct" approach depends on what the stored procedures are actually doing, and which ones you are (not) free to change. If you simply need to return the result set as-is to the caller (that is, you do not need to further process it) a syntactically correct `EXEC` will do.

Comment: It seems to me like you might be looking for "table valued functions", not stored procedures... see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-use-table-valued-user-defined-functions

Comment: @MarcGravell, unfortunaltely, my inner_proc makes heavy use of temp tables, and they are not permitted in table valued functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do further processing on the results? If not, the output will just be returned anyway.

If you do want to process further, create a temp table with the right columns

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
  nomAgence {type},
  chemin {type},
  ...  
)
```

then use select into

```
SELECT INTO #temp
EXEC SelectOFArbo( @DateMin, @DateMax, @idAgence, @nomAgence);
```

Note that SQL Server wont let you nest these calls, so SelectOfArbo could not SELECT-INSERT from another proc

Comment: IO table has 60 columns. Would be nice to use SELECT INTO. I mean would be nice to avoid having to list the column names and types.

Comment: @LudovicAubert: `SELECT * INTO #temp FROM OPENQUERY(localhost, 'EXEC ...')` can achieve that, but there are considerable drawbacks. [More info](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY). If it's just to save typing, don't go that way. You can use SSDT and even SSMS to limit the amount of keystrokes needed by generating `CREATE`/`INSERT`/`SELECT` statements; that only has to happen once.

Comment: Random tiny tip - if its just a case of not wanting to type, you can drag the "columns" folder under a table in SSMS object explorer into a query window and it will create a comma separated list of column names. You will still need to add the types to create the temp table, but it saves some time. Alternatively look at the XML method in Jeroen's link, though this is perhaps not any more elegant, though you can be selective in the columns you read from the XML